Find $S$ such that $P(X+Y\in S)\geq 0.9$ only using marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$
Let $X, Y$ be continuous random variables with their distributions $F_X, F_Y$, finite second moments and correlation $\rho$.
I would like to find a smallest possible set $S$ (set such that its Lebesgue measure is as small as possible) satisfying $$P(X+Y\in S)\geq 0.9.$$   The issue: $S$ can be ONLY a function of $F_X, F_Y, \rho$.
Would you have some idea on how to do that (possibly under some additional assumptions or at least some nontrivial special cases)?
A first intuitive guess gives me $S_{intuitive}:= S_x(0.95) + S_y(0.95)$, where $S_x(0.95)=(quantile_X(0.025), quantile_X(0.975))$ is a smallest set such that $P(X \in S_x(\alpha)) \geq\alpha$ and $S_y$ is defined analogously. I am using notation $A+B = \{a+b: a\in A, b\in B\}$ for two sets $A,B$. Can you find anything better?

What does shortest possible $S$ mean?

edited it. if its an interval, we just want it to be as short as possible, meaning minimizing its Lebesgue measure

$X$ and $Y$ are not independent, and their correlation and marginal CDFs will not be sufficient to describe their joint distribution or that of $X+Y$.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, you can often do better, but the lack of independence is an obstacle. So, to find worst case behaviour, you can try $Y = \lambda X$.

One way to get better bounds, at least in some cases, might be to distribute the risk in a different way: use $S_X (1-\alpha) + S_Y (1-\beta)$ with $\alpha+\beta = 0.1$, and optimize in $\alpha$. It might be interesting to see what the optimum is for Gaussians with different variances.

@D.Thomine if they are independent, can we do better? that is not clear to me as well, can you elaborate?
